# How to bind gridview on button click as empty grid is binding on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've form where I'm using gridview and I'm removing columns at runtime based on some condition and on button click event I'm binding the gridview by populating the datatable but it is showing empty grid with all empty rows only.

Gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="AccessControlGrid" GridLines="None" CssClass="wk-TableBorder" runat="server" 
                                        AutoGenerateColumns = "false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="There are no records.">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User No" HeaderStyle-CssClass="SpacerColumn gridheader1 GridColumnSpacing" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridColumnSpacing" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblUserNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserNo") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="SpacerColumn gridheader1 GridColumnSpacing" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridColumnSpacing" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_UserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Submit Original" HeaderStyle-CssClass="SpacerColumn gridheader1 GridColumnSpacing" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridColumnSpacing" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_FS_IsOriginal" AutoPostback = "True" OnCheckedChanged="Chk_CheckedChanged" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsOriginal")) %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Submit Continuation" HeaderStyle-CssClass="SpacerColumn gridheader1 GridColumnSpacing" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridColumnSpacing" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_FS_IsContinuation" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsContinuation")) %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Submit Debtor Amendment" HeaderStyle-CssClass="SpacerColumn gridheader1 GridColumnSpacing" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridColumnSpacing" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_FS_IsDebtorAmendment" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsDebtorAmendment")) %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Submit Secured Party Amendment" HeaderStyle-CssClass="SpacerColumn gridheader1 GridColumnSpacing" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridColumnSpacing" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_FS_IsSecPartyAmendment" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsSecPartyAmendment")) %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Submit Partial Assignment" HeaderStyle-CssClass="SpacerColumn gridheader1 GridColumnSpacing" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridColumnSpacing" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_FS_IsPartialAssignment" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsPartialAssignment")) %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Submit Full Assignment" HeaderStyle-CssClass="SpacerColumn gridheader1 GridColumnSpacing" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridColumnSpacing" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_FS_IsFullAssignment" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsFullAssignment")) %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Submit Termination" HeaderStyle-CssClass="SpacerColumn gridheader1 GridColumnSpacing" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridColumnSpacing" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_FS_IsTermination" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsTermination")) %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Submit Collateral Amendment" HeaderStyle-CssClass="SpacerColumn gridheader1 GridColumnSpacing" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridColumnSpacing" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_FS_IsCollateralAmendment" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsCollateralAmendment")) %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

On page load I just have to remove uwanted columns based on some condition and I've to hide the grid:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //This action will be performed once based on access type.
                AccessControlGridColumnAdjustment();
                AccessControlGrid.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

and finally on button click I've to populate and show grid:

```
protected void ImgBtnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (returnTable == null)
                returnTable = new DataTable("AccessControl");

            CreateAccessControlDataTable(ref returnTable, hdnAccessType.Value);
            LoadData();
            PopulateDataTable(ref returnTable, accessControlResultSet, hdnAccessType.Value);
            AccessControlGrid.DataSource = returnTable;
            AccessControlGrid.DataBind();
            AccessControlGrid.Visible = true;
        }
```

Inside CreateAccessControlDataTable I'm just creating the structure of Datatable based on some condition:

```
public DataTable CreateAccessControlDataTable(ref DataTable returnTable, string accessType)
        {
            try
            {
                #region Creating DataTable Schema for different access types
                switch (accessType)
                {
                    case "FS":
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserNo"));
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserName"));
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IsOriginal"));
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IsContinuation"));
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IsDebtorAmendment"));
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IsSecPartyAmendment"));
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IsPartialAssignment"));
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IsFullAssignment"));
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IsTermination"));
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IsCollateralAmendment"));
                        break;
                    case "IPF":
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserNo"));
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserName"));
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IsInPrepFilingDeletion"));
                        break;
                    case "FLD":
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserNo"));
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserName"));
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FloodStopAccess"));
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FloodReIssueAccess"));
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FloodLifeOfLoan"));
                        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FloodBasicCertificate"));
                        break;
                }
                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            return returnTable;
        }
```

Inside LoadData() and PopulateDataTable() function I'm just populating the empty Datatable with values from backend that is working fine but at the end I'm getting empty grid with multiple empty rows as below:

[image]

I've checked multiple threads here but nothing worked in my case.

> Note: If I do the same thing inside-  if (!IsPostback) {} then
> gridview loads properly but I don't have to do that, I've to load the
> grid based on search criteria at postback.

Comment: Are you looking to have empty values for those columns, or do you want the actual columns removed (not display) in the gv?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, I'm removing actual columns that are not supposed to be displayed for any particular role based on some condition at first page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we using templated columns (not auto generate). Then we need to deal with the columns we "are to hide".

This ALSO suggests that for at least those columns we hide, we can't really use binding expressions in the markup, since the given data source will not have those columns, and they will fail upon binding.

So, this suggests that we want to control the binding of those hide/show columns, and that of hiding/removing from the GV.

I also find that the instant we start to do such things, and the instant we have a LOT of templated controls, then I suggest using a listview in place of gridview. (There are a lot of reasons for this, one grid view simple reason is that the markup becomes less "cluttered" up since each control (standard asp.net controls) do not require a templated markup section, and then on top of that, you need an "item template" (this gets too messy too fast!).

However, let's put aside these reasons, and stick with the gv.

So, with a gridview, this is a bit of a bear to ride and tame, but this seems to be about the most workable.

Note: any optional column in the markup does not have a data binding expression (which would fail if data column is missing).

So, this markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID" Width="40%" GridLines="None"
            CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFirst" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblLast" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hotel Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblHotel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And this code to load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = @"SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description
                        FROM tblHotelsA
                        ORDER BY HotelName";

        GridView1.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

And our row data bind that looks for optional fields.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // all columns that are "optional" go here
    List<string> sOptional = 
        new List<string> { "FirstName:lblFirst:0", "LastName:lblLast:1", "City:lblCity:2" };

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView gBindData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

        foreach (string sHide in sOptional)
        {
            string sField = sHide.Split(':')[0];
            string sCtrl = sHide.Split(':')[1];
            int gCol = Convert.ToInt32(sHide.Split(':')[2]);

            if (gBindData.Row.Table.Columns.Contains(sField))
            {
                Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl(sCtrl);
                lbl.Text = gBindData["FirstName"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                GridView1.Columns[gCol].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, we define the optional columns. We do not use data bind expressions for optional columns (we bind them with code as per above. The above displays like this:

[image]

However, the above button click has this code:

```
    protected void cmdTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string strSQL = @"SELECT ID, HotelName, Description
                        FROM tblHotelsA
                        ORDER BY HotelName";

        GridView1.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

So, we left out of the data source the 3 optional columns.

The result is thus this:

[image]

So, with the above design, we just leave out the columns we don't want from the data source, and the rest of the code should just work.

## Edit: Not loading GV on first page load

To be more complete here, we have this code:

NB: a small edit was made to the row data bound (we have to re-enable (visible = true) for when we re-bind the gv.

So, say we now have this markup at start:

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdTest" runat="server" Text="Load data" 
            CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="cmdTest_Click"
            />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdTest2" runat="server" Text="Load Different data" 
            style="margin-left:20px"
            CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="cmdTest2_Click"
            />
        <br />
```

gv markup is un-changed.

And now the code is really much the same, and is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void cmdTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid();
    }

    protected void cmdTest2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strSQL = @"SELECT ID, HotelName, Description
                        FROM tblHotelsA
                        ORDER BY HotelName";


        GridView1.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = @"SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description
                        FROM tblHotelsA
                        ORDER BY HotelName";

        GridView1.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }


    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        // all columns that are "optional" go here
        List<string> sOptional = 
            new List<string> { "FirstName:lblFirst:0", "LastName:lblLast:1", "City:lblCity:2" };

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView gBindData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

            foreach (string sHide in sOptional)
            {
                string sField = sHide.Split(':')[0];
                string sCtrl = sHide.Split(':')[1];
                int gCol = Convert.ToInt32(sHide.Split(':')[2]);

                if (gBindData.Row.Table.Columns.Contains(sField))
                {
                    Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl(sCtrl);
                    lbl.Text = gBindData["FirstName"].ToString();
                    GridView1.Columns[gCol].Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    GridView1.Columns[gCol].Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And result is now this:

[image]

Note closely: the hide or show of columns will persist even when you do a full-rebind of the gv. (since your columns are tempalted).

This means if you hide a column (due to one data source bind), then those columns WILL retain their setting when you re-bind!

Solution: Your code that hides columns must also un-hide the columns!

So, this issue has nothing to do with the gv being loaded on page load or not. The issue of course is that if you bind the gv, hide some columns, and re-bind? Those columns will remain hidden, and they do not re-set their visible sitting on a re-bind.

## Edit 2: Get selected rows by user

Assume a check box in the grid. It can be bound to data, or not, does not matter.

So, add this markup to the gv.

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server"
                            checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>'
                            />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

And our data sources now include column Active:

eg this:

```
    protected void cmdTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid();
    }

    protected void cmdTest2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strSQL = @"SELECT ID, HotelName, Description, Active
                        FROM tblHotelsA
                        ORDER BY HotelName";


        GridView1.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = @"SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description, Active
                        FROM tblHotelsA
                        ORDER BY HotelName";

        GridView1.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

And right after the gv, say we have this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdShowChecked" runat="server" Text="Get Selected" 
            style="margin-left:20px"
            CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="cmdShowChecked_Click"
            />
        <asp:Label ID="lblSelected" runat="server" Text=""
            style="margin-left:30px">
        </asp:Label>
```

So, result is now this:

[image]

Code for selected button click after gv is this:

```
   protected void cmdShowChecked_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sPKIDSelected = "";
        foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            string sPK = GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"].ToString();

            CheckBox chkSel = (CheckBox)gRow.FindControl("chkActive");
            if (chkSel.Checked)
            {
                if (sPKIDSelected != "")
                    sPKIDSelected += ",";

                sPKIDSelected += sPK;
            }
        }

        string strSQL = $@"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA
                        WHERE ID IN ({sPKIDSelected})
                        ORDER BY HotelName";

        DataTable MySelected = General.MyRst(strSQL);

        lblSelected.Text =
            $"PK database ID selected = {sPKIDSelected} Rows Selected = {MySelected.Rows.Count}";
        // do whatever with selected data table items
    }
```

Comment: but I don't have to display the grid on Page load, grid needs to be displayed on button click only(in postback).

Comment: The code I have in page load to load the gv first time would and could be removed. (call mommy - she can comment out 3 lines of code???). The posted code is a proof of concept, and if you say have 2 buttons to load 2 different data sources was the REAL proof of concept posted here. The fact that my exampled loaded gv on first page load, and then a button click to load a different dataset does not change how the posted code works. So, the concepts and code does not require gv load code. So, say we have 2 buttons to load 2 different data sources then, right? I'll edit and show this.

Comment: See my edit, note that you MUST UN-HIDE the controls on a new data bind. The settings of hidden columns REMAINS in effect EVEN when you re-bind. So, if you have hidden columns, you have to un-hide them. See my 2nd edit + example. For any column that you "can hide", then the code has to "un-hide" for a new data source.

Comment: that works absolutely fine, could you please tell me how can I find some control based on any checkbox check/uncheck event of any gridview row, I'm using following code but it is not working:
protected void Chk_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (AccessControlGrid.SelectedRow.FindControl("hdnDirty") as HiddenField).Value = "true";
            bool isChecked = Convert.ToBoolean((AccessControlGrid.SelectedRow.FindControl("hdnDirty") as HiddenField).Value);
            foreach (Control c in AccessControlGrid.SelectedRow.Controls)
        { }
        }

Comment: See my edit, I show addition of a check box per row. that check box can be bound to data, or not - don't matter. See the edit and code that shows how to get/grab the selected row, and even how to create a SQL query based on those selected rows.